# How to fetch files from a directory and execute them parallely 5 at a time

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I'm Using to ant to fetch all files in a directory and execute only 5 files parallely and next 5 five again. Already executed file should not be executed again.

```
<target name="ParallelTest" description="Checking the parallelTest">
        <for param="file" >
            <path> 
                <fileset dir="C:/RCBuild3/ofs/bin/prd1">
                        <include name="*.xml"/> 
                </fileset>
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <antcall target="parallelexecutoin">
                    <param name="productfile" value="@{file}"/>
                </antcall>
            </sequential>
        </for> 

    </target>
    <target name="parallelexecutoin">
        <exec dir="C:/RCBuild3/ofs/bin/" executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="productupload.bat"/>
            <arg value="-fileName"/>
            <arg value="${productfile}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

The Above code executes sequentially .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code first:

```
<fileset dir="C:/RCBuild3/ofs/bin/prd1" id="src.files">
    <include name="*.xml"/> 
</fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="," property="file.list" refid="src.files"/>

<for list="${file.list}" delimiter="," param="file" parallel="true" threadCount="5">
    <sequential>
        <antcall target="parallelexecutoin">
            <param name="productfile" value="@{file}"/>
        </antcall>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Explain:

First of all, you prepare a `fileset` for all the files that need to be processed.

Then, use `pathconvert` to convert the fileset to a property "file.list" like: `filename1.xml,filename2.xml,filename3.xml`.

`for` task's java code (which hides behind your Ant file) will split "file.list" using comma into a `List`, and loop through the `List`. For each element in the `List`, the loop body (`sequential` part) will run.

`parallel` tells `for` task to run the loop body with multiple threads, and `threadcount` is the maximium number of threads that could be running at the same time.

So with `parallel = true` and `threadcount = 5`, is acts exactly as what you described: 5 files a time.